# Regular expression for a String to mask digits except last 4 in xml tag content

Tags: java, regex, data-masking

this is an account number 77787845456464645656547877

accountNumber1.replaceAll( "(desc>||desc\s*[:]{2}\s*?|)(\d(?=\d{4}))", "$1XXXXXXXXXX$2") This is not working,I tried different ways no result .Pl check ,thx

Comment: Does it _have to be_ a regular expression?  Lots of ways to do this that don't involve a regex...

Comment: Maybe something like this [`\d+(?=\d{4})`](https://regex101.com/r/sFgKNE/1/).

Comment: *"My regex skill is quite low"* Now would be a great time to **learn** more. This is not a do-the-work-for-me site, or a teaching site.

Comment: If your *regex skill is quite low* and you *don't know where to start*, you have two choices: 1) Improve your regex skills enough to try to do it yourself, or 2) find a solution that doesn't involve a regex. It's not going to do you any good to get a regex here that you don't understand and don't have any ability to maintain or modify yourself.

Answer (score 2):

An approach without regex:

```
char[] cs = accountNum.toCharArray();
Arrays.fill(cs, 0, cs.length-4, '*');
String masked = new String(cs);
```

Comment: I like your back to basics no-nonsense approach.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to replace every digit with a `*`, provided it's followed by four or more other digits.  Do the last part with a forward lookup, something like

```
myString.replaceAll("\\d(?=\\d{4})", "*");
```

which returns `myString` with every digit other than the last four replaced with `*`.

Comment: <desc>this is an account number 77787845456464645656547877</desc>                                                             accountNumber1.replaceAll(
    "(desc>|<desc\\S*\\s\\S*\\W>|desc\\s*[:]{2}\\s*?|<desc\\S*\\s\\S*\\W>)(\\d(?=\\d{4}))",
    "$1XXXXXXXXXX$2")          This is not working,I tried different ways no result .Pl check ,thx

Comment: I want the string content along with last 4 of the number .Pl check the above one ,Thx

Comment: I see that you've replaced your original question with something quite different.  You shouldn't do that after people start answering your question.  If you have a new question, then _ask_ a new question.